# Why I'm getting the below error when running SQL with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

This is my sql

```
SELECT
  date,
  name,
  post
FROM
  [dataset.table]
WHERE
  date='2019-05-01';
```

This is the error

> Error: Argument type mismatch in function EQUAL: 'date' is type int32, '2019-05-01' is type string

Comment: provide example of your data specifically field `date` - as you see from error message  - it is integer while you compare it with string thus the error. most likely your `date` looks like 20190501 or something similar  - please clarify so we will be able to help you

Comment: i am getting this error after table partition

Comment: Row date name post  
1 2019-04-01 vinay manager  
2 2019-04-03 surbhi eng  
3 2019-05-01 bhupendra test  
4 2019-05-02 aniket sr.software.eng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a specific example for the format of data inside your `date` parameter this is impossible to give an exact working answer.

That said, you will need to specify that `'2019-05-01'` is a date, with `date('2019-05-01')`.

Regarding your `date` parameter you will need to cast it to a date. Assuming it is currently formatted as an epoch timestamp the following will work: `DATE(TIMESTAMP(date))`.

So you would end up with something like:

```
WHERE 
    DATE(TIMESTAMP(date)) = date('2019-05-01')
```

It's worth mentioning that `date` is probably not a good parameter name.